# Parse Json data and inserting into Yaml

Tags: json, jenkins, yaml, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Using a jenkins pipeline I want to parse a json file and append some value to one of my Yaml file. Below is my Json file.

```
{
  "id": "test",
  "chef": {
    "attributes": {
      "example": {
        "example": "test"
      }
    },
    "run_list": [
      "recipe[example::example]"
    ] 
  }
}
```

And, here is how my Yaml file looks:

```
id: example
components:
  component1:
    type: example1
    data:
      action:
        first: FullClone
      chef:
        default: '{"example1": { "value1": "test123" }, "run_list": ["recipe[example1::example123"]}'
  component2:
    type: example2
```

Here is the pipeline script that I am using:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage {
      stpes {
        jsonData = readJSON file: 'test.json'
        yamlData = readYaml file: 'test.yaml'
        parsedJsonData = jsonData.chef
        yamlData['components']['component1']['data']['chef']['default'] = "$parsedJsonData"
        writeYaml file: 'newYaml.yaml', data: yamlData
        sh "cat newYaml.yaml"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output I am getting is like this:

```
id: example
status: DR
components:
  component1:
    type: example1
    data:
      action:
        first: FullClone
      chef:
        default: '[attributes:[example:[example:test]], run_list:[recipe[example::example]]]'
  component2:
    type: example2
```

But I am excepting the output like this:

```
id: example
components:
  component1:
    type: example1
    data:
      action:
        first: FullClone
      chef:
        default: '{"example": { "example": "test" }, "run_list": ["recipe[example::example"]}'
  component2:
    type: example2
```

Comment: you don't want "attributes:..." on your result ? it miss a "{" somewhere to have a good result. Can you fix it well plz ? I don't understand what do you expect exactly.

Comment: i think waht he expect, is in default field,  is not the same data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is this line:

```
yamlData['components']['component1']['data']['chef']['default'] = "$parsedJsonData"
```

The problem being the `"$parsedJsonData"` part.

This will call the `toString()` method of the interpolated data, which appears to be a `Map`.

To convert it to the JSON string representation, you could make use of the  [`groovy.json.JsonOutput.html#toJson(java.util.Map)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.13/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonOutput.html#toJson(java.util.Map)) method in your pipeline instead.

If it is indeed a `Map` (or a few other types) it will be whitelisted by default by the *Script Security Plugin* (see [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/38e6f6f7850b539a9a430d6ce5fd8c2e146a3181/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/generic-whitelist#L5-L14)). If not, it may be blacklisted (see [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/38e6f6f7850b539a9a430d6ce5fd8c2e146a3181/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/blacklist#L2-L3)).

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

// ...
yamlData['components']['component1']['data']['chef']['default'] = JsonOutput.toJson(parsedJsonData)
```

Comment: Can you help me to get the value of the `attribute` and `runlist` in the variable `parsedJsonData `

Comment: @linuxnewbee I think you can use the same access pattern you did for the  - `parsedJsonData['chef']['runlist']` and `parsedJsonData['chef']['attributes']`